# CSS don't want to see text below Icon

Tags: css, reactjs

I am using react to display icon on the left and span div on the right. I don't want to have the text below the icon. It should align nicely to the right.

[image]

```
export const MMText = styled.span`
font-family: Myanmar3;
font-size: 10px;
`;

export const BulletIcon = styled(Icon)`
color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.25);
margin-right: 10px;
`;

const MMBulletText = ({ text }) => (
  <div>
    <BulletIcon type="star" />
    <MMText> {text} </MMText>
    <br />
    <br />
  </div>
);
```

Comment: Could you show the code you have written so far? It might be easier for us to help you then.

Comment: alright sure! thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [flexbox](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Flexible_Box_Layout/Basic_Concepts_of_Flexbox). Something like this :

(Obviously `.icon` can contain anything, not just text. In your case a svg icon, font icon, img or something like that)

```css
.wrapper {
  display: flex;
}

.icon {
  margin-right: 10px;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <span class="icon">Icon</span>
  <span class="text">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Assumenda suscipit alias qui cupiditate eligendi incidunt optio, eveniet commodi tempore accusantium molestiae quibusdam similique consequuntur, nobis voluptatum, accusamus reiciendis porro sit.</span>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Using flex layout for the container div can help.

```js
const FlexContainer = styled.div`
display: flex;
`;

export const MMText = styled.span`
font-family: Myanmar3;
font-size: 10px;
`;

export const BulletIcon = styled(Icon)`
color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.25);
margin-right: 10px;
`;

const MMBulletText = ({ text }) => (
  <FlexContainer>
    <BulletIcon type="star" />
    <MMText> {text} </MMText>
    <br />
    <br />
  </FlexContainer>
);
```

Comment: this works! but icon goes up abit, no longer align with text?